# How to rewrite this command using \newenvironment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, environments

I once defined a customized latex command, which works well. And now I would like to convert it into a latex environment using \newenvironment command. 
However, I failed after trying several ways. 
Could you help me, please?

The definition of my own latex command is

```
\newcommand{\smallbox}[1]{
    \tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, rectangle,inner sep=5pt, inner ysep=5pt]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [mybox] (box){
                \begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth}
                     #1
                \end{minipage}
            };
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}
```

Let's call the to-be-defined enviroment "smallenvironment" for the moment.

And I would like that, the following command

```
\smallbox{This is a small box!}
```

is equivalent to

```
\begin{smallenvironment}
    This is a small box!
\end{smallenvironment}
```

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm not sure you can split a node like that. It seems you only want to draw a frame around the minipage... have you considered using the `mdframed` package instead?

Comment: Why do you want to convert it into an environment? Is there some 'begin code' and 'end code'? Which content is to come before or after the box? And did you have a look on `\tcolorbox` package, e.g.?

Answer (score 7):

With the help of `\NewEnviron` from the `environ` package

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{smallenvironment}{%
    \tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, rectangle,inner sep=5pt, inner ysep=5pt]%
    \begin{center}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \node [mybox] (box){%
                \begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth}%
                     \BODY
                \end{minipage}%
            };%
       \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{center}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{smallenvironment}
This is a small box!
\end{smallenvironment}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another way, as egreg notes in his comment, is to keep your definition of `\smallbox` and simply say

```
\NewEnviron{smallenvironment}{\smallbox{\BODY}}
```

---

### EDIT

Note that an environment like the above can be obtained in a much simpler way with the help of the `mdframed` package.

Take a look at the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\smallbox}[1]{
    \tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, rectangle,inner sep=5pt, inner ysep=5pt]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node [mybox] (box){
                \begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth}
                     #1
                \end{minipage}
            };
       \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
}

\NewEnviron{smallenvironment}{\smallbox{\BODY}}

\newmdenv[%
    linecolor=red,
    innerleftmargin=5pt,
    innerrightmargin=5pt,
    leftmargin=20pt,
    rightmargin=20pt
  ]{smallmdframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{smallenvironment}
This is a small box!
\end{smallenvironment}

\begin{smallmdframe}
This is a small box!
\end{smallmdframe}

\end{document}
```

and at its output

[image]

Comment: Why not `\NewEnviron{smallenv}{\smallbox{\BODY}}` keeping the command definition?

Comment: @egreg You're right. I'll add it in the answer.

Comment: Having both forms can be handy. However, if the purpose is just to draw a frame, using `mdframed` or `tcolorbox` could be better.

Comment: @user49768 Remember that you can accept the answer that helped you most. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)

Answer (score 3):

Karl has already shown you about forming a newenvironment using `environ`. I will point out some improvements to your `tikzpicture` code.

1. Use `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle`.
2. No need of specifying `ysep` when you have already `inner sep`.
3. No need of using `minipage` inside the node. You can specify `text width= 0.85\textwidth, minimum width = 0.85\textwidth` in `node` options, making it more `tikz` way.
4. Instead of `begin{center}` and `\end{center}` you may use `\centering` if you want to avoid extra vertical space.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{smallenvironment}{%
    \tikzset{mybox/.style = {draw=red, rectangle,inner sep=5pt}}%
    \begin{center}%     %% \centering         
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \node [mybox,text width= 0.85\textwidth, minimum width = 0.85\textwidth] (box){%
               \BODY
            };%
       \end{tikzpicture}%
       \end{center}    %% \par %% if you use \centering
}

\begin{document}
Some text

\begin{smallenvironment}
This is a small box!
\end{smallenvironment}

Some text
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\centering`, you get

[image]